# Date time object from webservice showing on Android textview with pattern?

Tags: java, android, json

Hi I have web service that return a date object like this as a return of the Json

```
 "/Date(922312800000+0200)/"
```

However i need to show it on the textview in this pattern

```
"19.12.2011 16:15"
```

how can I convert that return to this pattern ?

Edit : Here is my code still giving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String dateText = date.format(tempEntry.getCreatedDate());
```

Edit : Here is the code that work for me

```
String dateText = tempEntry.getCreatedDate();
String dateString = dateText.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
String[] dateParts = dateString.split("[+-]");
Date dateFormat = new Date(Long.parseLong(dateParts[0]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that your Date is given in milliseconds from 1970, so, something like that:

```
// remove the unneeded information
String date = date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/"); 
String[] dateParts = date.split("[+-]")
//get the date represented by the given millis
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(Long.parseLong(dateParts[0]);
// proceed with formatting to the desired date format.
```

Comment: your answer slighly did the trick , but Calendar does not have long parameter constructor so i am using Date object thanks i put the code to question...

Comment: @Burak Dede - yes, it has a setter for the time. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use: [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html).

Simple example:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String today = formatter.format(date);
textView.setText("Today : " + today);
```

Comment: I put the code that gives exception , i used before and again it is giving illegal argument exception...